# Callback function "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jsonp, tumblr

I am building a script that fetches multiple JSON feeds from Tumblr and creates HTML lists based on that data. Pretty straightforward concept.

Here's the output: http://fotis.co/tumblr/index.html

The script is partly working as I'm stumbling on "callback function not defined" issues. That happens only when I choose to use a callback function when requesting the Tumblr JSON feed. By default, if you don't specify a callback function via the Tumblr API, the JSON object returned is assigned to a variable named tumblr_api_read. So the JSON actually returns:

```
var tumblr_api_read = {the JSON object data goes here};
```

If I use a callback function, the JSON data is returned like this (as expected):

```
callbackFunctionName({the JSON object data goes here});
```

If you check out the script code here http://fotis.co/tumblr/tumblr.js:

```
/* Read Tumblr */

function ready(cb) {
    /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('ready('+cb+')', 9) : cb();
}

function getTumblrFeed(params) {
    /*
    Legend:
    start - The post offset to start from. The default is 0.
    num - The number of posts to return. The default is 20, and the maximum is 50.
    type - The type of posts to return. If unspecified or empty, all types of posts are returned. Must be one of text, quote, photo, link, chat, video, or audio.
    id - A specific post ID to return. Use instead of start, num, or type.
    filter - Alternate filter to run on the text content. Allowed values:
        text - Plain text only. No HTML.
        none - No post-processing. Output exactly what the author entered. (Note: Some authors write in Markdown, which will not be converted to HTML when this option is used.)
    tagged - Return posts with this tag in reverse-chronological order (newest first). Optionally specify chrono=1 to sort in chronological order (oldest first).
    search - Search for posts with this query.
    */
    if(params.blogurl) var blogurl = params.blogurl;
    if(params.postcount) var num = params.postcount;
    var jsonurl = document.location.protocol+ '//' +blogurl+ '/api/read/json?num=' +num;
    if(params.type) jsonurl += '&type=' + params.type;
    if(params.tagged) jsonurl += '&tagged=' + params.tagged;
    if(params.search) jsonurl += '&search=' + params.search;
    if(params.callback) jsonurl += '&callback=' + params.callback;
    var jsonfeedscript = document.createElement('script');
    jsonfeedscript.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
    jsonfeedscript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    jsonfeedscript.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    jsonfeedscript.setAttribute('src', jsonurl);
    return jsonfeedscript;
}

function renderResults(settings) {
    var tumblrObj = (settings.callback) ? settings.callback : tumblr_api_read;

    var i = 0;
    var c = document.getElementById(settings.container);

    for(i; i<tumblrObj.posts.length; i++){
        // URL
        var postUrl = tumblrObj.posts[i]['url-with-slug'];
        // Title
        if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['regular-title']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['regular-title'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['quote-text']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['quote-text'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['link-text']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['link-text'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['audio-caption']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['audio-caption'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['photo-caption']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['photo-caption'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['video-caption']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['video-caption'];
        } else if(tumblrObj.posts[i]['conversation-text']){
            var postTitle = tumblrObj.posts[i]['conversation-text'];
        } else {
            var postTitle = '';
        }
        // Date
        var postDate = tumblrObj.posts[i]['date']; // or: date-gmt, unix-timestamp
        // Type
        var postType = tumblrObj.posts[i]['type'];
        // Output
        var output = settings.theme.replace("{postUrl}",postUrl).replace("{postTitle}",postTitle).replace("{postDate}",postDate);
        c.innerHTML += output;
    }

    // Hide the loader
    var l = document.getElementById(settings.loader);
    c.removeChild(l);
}

function readTumblr(settings) {
    // Load JSON data
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var jsonfeedscript = getTumblrFeed(settings);
    head.appendChild(jsonfeedscript);

    jsonfeedscript.onload = function(){
        renderResults(settings);
    }
}
```

You will see that I do a check if the JSON feed is invoked with a callback function (inside readTumblr()), otherwise I just use the default object "tumblr_api_read". If no callback function is defined where the script is initialized (inside index.html) the Tumblr JSON data are properly rendered (see Containers 2 and 3 in the html output). If I DO define a callback function, I get something like "callbackFunctioName is not defined" and then rendering fails.

Am I missing something here? Is it a scope issue? And if so, how can I bypass it?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

**EDIT 1**: Updated script code above.

Comment: Sorted it out on my own. The trick is to dynamically create the callback function on the window object, so you can then use it. Although not Tumblr-specific (as the above demo), I use this technique here: http://demo.joomlaworks.gr/allvideos - the js creating the dynamic callback functions is referenced in http://demo.joomlaworks.gr/plugins/content/jw_allvideos/includes/js/behaviour.js - It's how the SoundCloud and Blip.tv embeds work - enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a callback to a JSONP API, you'll get back a JavaScript snippet that calls whatever function you supplied with the JSON data as an argument. As you noted:

```
callbackFunctionName({the JSON object data goes here});
```

The JSONP/callback system all depends on *your code* having already defined the `callbackFunctionName` function, so there's something to be called. The idea is, you put your code that needs to work on the Tumblr data in that callback function.

If you prefer working with the `var tumblr_api_read` way of doing things, just don't specify a callback.

Otherwise, you'd basically want to move what you currently have as `jsonfeedscript.onload` to whatever function you're defining as the callback. As an example, if you gave the Tumblr API a "callback" parameter of "myCallback", your code should look basically like:

```
function myCallback(tumblrObj) {
    // Your code that reads the JSON and inserts the HTML
}
```

You don't then ever need to call `myCallback` *yourself*. You just make the JSONP request by inserting the `script` tag, and the Tumblr API will give you back a script that calls `myCallback` and passes in the JSON data.

Comment: So you're saying the callback function should already be defined elsewhere in the script, before fetching the JSON data? Of course the script works without the callback, but fetching multiple Tumblr JSON feeds and passing them to the same variable, isn't that a bad practice?

Comment: The callback function *must* be defined already, before you try to make the JSONP call (because it will send you back a script that tries to *call* that callback function). And I'd agree: using a callback is probably preferable to just letting the Tumblr API assign to a particular variable.

Comment: Even if I manually define the callback function (in this case, if I just write var javascript = new Function();) at the root of the script, the JSON data are still not properly read...

Comment: Have you checked my last edit to this answer (the `myCallback` part in particular)? The callback function doesn't get changed, altered or created by the JSONP callback, so defining a callback function that's just empty does you no good. The idea is: the callback is where your code that works on the data is supposed to go. You put your *implementation* there, then the API call just supplies the data by *calling* your callback function.

Comment: I find it difficult to translate the dynamic parameter "settings.callback" to a callback function... (btw thank you very much for your help so far in clearing up many things)

Comment: I updated the readTumblr() function to abstract the output logic.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line:

`tumblrObj = (settings.callback) ? settings.callback : tumblr_api_read`

be:

`tumblrObj = (settings.callback) ? settings.callback() : tumblr_api_read`

?

I'm not sure, it looks weird to me.

Comment: settings.callback is just a parameter set where we invoke the script (aka inside the index.html file).